# How do I use chrome.tabs.executeScript in chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm messing around with chrome extensions, and I'm trying to inject some JS into the page. (I want to, for example, make the main page popup a box saying something). Here's my JS file:

```
//Function to be called:
function setText() {
  var text = document.getElementById("titleinput").value;
  var myCode="alert('Test');";
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:myCode});
}

//Makes it run above code when a button is pressed:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', setText);
});
```

And here's my manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "Tester",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "description",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

I know the `setText()` is being called (I tried putting an alert directly in there), but for some reason the main page isnt making a popup saying 'Test' like it should. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are running it on a website and not `chrome://extensions`. You can't inject scripts into `chrome://*` pages. If it still isn't working use the [popup debugger](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup) to look for errors.

Comment: The popup debugger helped, got it fixed :P